# fancybox slider script not working in i7 and i8

Tags: jquery

http://174.120.232.253/~priya/Parthvi/wordpress/NobelConcert/

in this link we use Fancybox slider and it is  not working in i7 and i8 and refrence link for this slider.
http://webdesignandsuch.com/fancymoves-jquery-product-slider-2/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are loading jQuery twice on the same page, which can cause lots of problems.

http://174.120.232.253/~priya/Parthvi/wordpress/NobelConcert/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1

and

http://174.120.232.253/~priya/Parthvi/wordpress/NobelConcert/wp-content/FancyMoves/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Comment: The first jquery is the default wordpres jquery. If i added that in header in place of second one it will make the slider not work.

Comment: Can you please suggest what i can do?

Comment: You should remove the second jQuery. If you need the latest version, you should update the Wordpress jQuery

Comment: yes,we have removed the second jquery and working on new version  of wordpress and have updated jquery in that..but till slider is not working.what should we do now..?

Comment: anyone know about this problem please reply